# JPA throws lazy loading exception even it is eager fetch

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    //A user can be employee in many organizations so he look at the same time as many emplyee
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "user-association")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Association> associations;
```

....
Association entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ASSOCIATION")
public class Association implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private AssociationId associationId;
    private String permission;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "user-association")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "organization-association")
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Organization organization;
```

POST endpoint

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/{id}/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<User> associateUserToOrganization(@RequestBody AssociationDTO userToOrgDTO, @PathVariable String id) {
        Association association = new Association(new AssociationId(userToOrgDTO.getUserId(), userToOrgDTO.getOrganizationId()));
        association.setPermission("GUEST_SET");
        User userToAffect = userRepository.findById(userToOrgDTO.getUserId()).get();
        Organization orgToAffect = organizationRepository.findById(userToOrgDTO.getOrganizationId()).get();
        userToAffect.addAssociation(association);
        orgToAffect.addAssociation(association);
        organizationRepository.save(orgToAffect);
        return userRepository.findAll().stream().filter(user -> !user.getAssociations().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

When I add a user to the organization using POSTMAN with correct input, the famous error of serialization of lazy loading appears even I am not using fetch type Lazy

this is the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->jpa.workspace.manytomanyadditional.domain.User$HibernateProxy$pL9wPAuw["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

So i made the solution as it is mentioned in this exception and i put in **application.properties**,

```
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

and `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` to remove it from the json

The issue is fixed sure, but why I am supposed to consider the User->associations relationship as Lazy fetching and not eager as I chose it...Is it related to `@JsonManagedReference`  maybe?

am using spring 2.4.1 and hibernate (core 5.4.25 & annotations 5.1.2 Final)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@JsonManagedReferenced`, `@JsonBackReference` and add these following in your config class

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(jackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}

@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(jacksonBuilder().build());

    return converter;
}

public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();

    Hibernate5Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();
    hibernateModule.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);

    builder.modules(hibernateModule);
    builder.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    builder.featuresToDisable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);

    return builder;
}
```

Comment: so it is about the default config, but why it doesn't load the default config of EAGER fetching, it should be (lazy config XOR eager config), any other explanation on JsonManagedReferenced!!! does this annotation enable LAZY loading config instead EAGER?

Comment: When loading data with `Model` in `@Controller` for the purpose of displaying it for example in thymeleaf template, you dont need any config, the default fetchType will be fired. But as soon as you want to serialize your object to return it as json, there is recursive call. Parent -> Children -> Parent ... And it ends up with issues